# VS Code 1.85+ with FLOATING WINDOWS: How to minimize all windows at once?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode 1.85+ has floating windows (but not floating panels, or sidebars, but that's another story).   How can I make it so if I click minimize in the top right of a floater, ALL floating windows, AND the parent, are minimized?

#2:  related:  when restoring any ONE of the windows, how can I get ALL windows to restore?